OpenMP, CMake, and Clang on Apple M2 machine
I am currently trying to build and run the simplest OpenMP project on Mac (Apple M2 Pro, macOS Sonoma 14.6.1) using CMake (3.31).
main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "omp.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

#pragma omp parallel
    cout << "hello openmp from thread " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;

    return 0;
}

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(omp_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fopenmp")

add_executable(omp_test main.cpp)

When trying cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. and then make, I got:
clang++: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'

I suppose it means that Apple Clang does not support OpenMP by default (I can't use g++ as it does not support Arm64). What I tried after Google:

Install via Homebrew:

brew install llvm libomp


Set the environment: Add the following lines into ~/.zshrc and ``

export CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"


Change the CMakeLists.txt:

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(omp_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
if(OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    target_compile_options(omp_test PRIVATE OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS)
    target_link_libraries(omp_test OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "OpenMP not found")
endif()

add_executable(omp_test main.cpp)

After that, when trying cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .., I got:
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:233 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:603 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/FindOpenMP.cmake:616 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

How to solve this issue?

Have you tried not linking it explicitly and letting the #pragmas take care of it? If you do not get any "#pragma ignored" warnings during compilation, it means that the compiler detected the #pragma, understood it and invoked openmp appropriately. You shouldn't even need #include "omp.h. Use Apple clang to test this out (remove the export lines you added to ~/.zshrc).
